# Jest/Express: Tests fail with Async error only when there are multiple describe blocks

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, jestjs

I have a Jest test file in my Express backend that works perfectly when it contains one `describe()` block. However, as soon as another describe block is added, I get this error regardless of how long I set the timeout:

`Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 30000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.`

If I add the second describe block to a separate file, both of them run just fine and their combine run time is less than 30 seconds. But I don't see any reason to create a new file every time I want a new test suite.

Here is an extremely simplified version of both suites:

```
jest.setTimeout(30000);

describe('Mealplan Model Test', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await db.Connection;
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await mongoose.connection.close();
  });

  it('create & save mealPlan successfully', async (done) => {
    // Test logic
  });

  // You shouldn't be able to add in any field that isn't defined in the schema
  it('insert mealplan successfully, but the extra field does not persist', async (done) => {
    // test logic
  });


  // etc
});

describe('Create User recipes and foods based on admin versions', () => {
  let foodAdmin, recipeAdmin, user;
  
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await db.Connection;
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await mongoose.connection.close();
  });

  it('creates user recipe based on admin recipe', async () => {
    // test logic
  });

  it('returns the correct userRecipe if one already exists', async () => {
    // test logic
    
  });
  // etc
});
```

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7434 possibly related

Comment: @Anthony Having read through this, I don't think so. In my case both test suites pass successfully when they're on their own, so it's not a matter of tests continuing to run despite a failure. What I want is to be able to include multiple describe blocks in one test file and have them both work. It's ok if one fails for the other one to run.

Comment: Can you see what happens if you remove the `done` from the arguments in the `it` blocks?

Answer (score 0):

`describe` itself isn't supposed to affect how tests run, this happens because of multiple `afterAll`. `mongoose.connection.close()` closes the connection but it's not re-opened in `beforeAll`.

Mongoose chains connection promise for any promises it creates, this results in pending promise if a connection is
never established.

If `describe` groups reuse the same connection, a connection should be closed only once at top level:

```
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await db.Connection;
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await mongoose.connection.close();
  });
```

Comment: So we should only have one `await db.Connection` at the beginning of the file in the first describe block, and at the end of the file one `await mongoose.connection.close();`

Comment: You can omit top-level describe, it's optional in Jest. They can be at the top, the position of before* and after* blocks doesn't matter, only the order of similar blocks.

Comment: Got it, the thing is I can't consolidate the beforeAll and afterAll because I do actually have other database actions happening in each describe block that are specific to that set of test cases. But are you saying I can have two beforeAll and afterAll as long as they're in the correct order?